# Jekyll liquid find and where filters don't work if string begins with 0

Tags: json, jekyll, liquid

Not sure if this is a bug or I am misunderstanding but say you have .json file like

```
[
    {
      "example": "012",
    },
    {
      "example": "A012",
    }
]
```

Then you won't be able to find or where like:

```
{% assign var1 = site.data.myjsonfile | find:"example", "012" %}
{% assign var1 = site.data.myjsonfile | where:"example", "012" | first %}
```

will return blank instead of any json object.

But works if you just access via index like:

```
{% assign var1 = site.data.myjsonfile[0] %}
```